# Explanation of Melting Point's power?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In **Flash *S04E18*** Caitlin in the form of *Killer Frost* touches DeVoe and her powers are gone. Later in the episode, it is explained that the Thinker used Melting Point's power to do so. But as far as I know, Melting Point can just transfer the power of a meta, to any person he touched, he cannot take away the power completely. So who gets the powers of *Killer Frost*? Is it the Thinker or anyone else.

Or can *Melting Point* completely take away a metahuman's power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of S5E06 it has been revealed that DeVoe did not in fact use Melting Point's powers to prevent Caitlin becoming Killer Frost - instead he used Brain Storm's powers to place a mental block on the transformation.

This is why Caitlin showed all the signs of still having Killer Frost within her, but was unable to physically change over and access her powers.

The events of the episode

> which involve her fighting her newly found father's cryo-psycho personality and managing to overcome the mental block due to her friends dying on the floor around her

show that there is a way back for Caitlin to reassert her powers.

> Using the mental inhibitor to affect the mental block, Caitlin is able to once more converse in her head with the Killer Frost persona.

Answer (score 4):

> But as far as I know, Melting Point can just transfer the power of a meta to any person he touched he cannot take away the power completely.

We know from the episode *Subject 9* that the bus metas are not completely aware of the full extent of their powers:

1. Dominic Lanse, initially known to be able to read minds, can manipulate brains. Devoe uses his power to stop Barry by giving him an aneurysm in the same episode, and use the power to wipe his wife's memory.
2. Ralph Dibny firstly used his ability to change his body shape in a rough way (extremely long arms for example). He soon discovers the great extent of his power, in that he can shape-shift and take the appearance of anyone he wants.
3. In episode S04E18 *Losing yourself*, DeVoe explained that Janet Petty didn't know how powerful she was: in addition of being able to make people fly (and fall!), she can alter gravity to give something or someone more weight. DeVoe prevented Barry to move by giving him the weight of a truck.

Then it is reasonable to consider that Melting Point didn't fully master his power. Instead of transfering a power from someone to another person, he may be able to retain the power he just has stolen. After all, the core of Melting Point's power is DNA manipulation, so it is not completely crazy.

> So who gets the powers of Killer Frost? Is it the thinker or anyone else. Or can Melting Point completely take away a metas power.

Can Melting Point/Devoe use Killer Frost's power now? If no, is the power lost for good? Can he retain more than one power at once? I'd say we will have the answer in future episodes.